# How can I make a scrollbar automatically be in the center or right side of content?

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive, hebrew

I have a table which is using [Bootstrap's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) `table-responsive` class in order to fit it on mobile screens. This clips of all the x-axis overflowed data and adds a scrollbar taking advantage of the CSS `overflow-x` property.

Since my table content is in Hebrew, the table content is being clipped off the wrong way. The content that stays visible should be hidden. I'm getting

[image: The table view I'm currently getting]

instead of this:

[image: The table view I should be getting]

How can I make the scrollbar appear at the right side or center of content instead of left side? (The scrollbar isn't visible in pictures, because it's on mobile.)

The code below reproduces my problem:

```css
table
{
  max-width: 250px;
  overflow-x: auto;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table-responsive table">
  <tr>
    <td>data point</td>
    <td>data point</td>
    <td>data point</td>
    <td>data point</td>
    <td>data point</td>
    <td>data point</td>
    <td>data point</td>
    <td>
      <form>
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
    </td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perhaps add some information about the mobile platform you have tried it on - presumably in a web browser (browser (including version) and operating system (including version)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood the question correctly, I think you want to specify the direction with this:  `dir="rtl"`

```css
table
{
  max-width:250px;
  overflow-x:auto;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table-responsive table"  dir="rtl">
  <tr>
    <td>data point</td>
    <td>data point</td>
    <td>data point</td>
    <td>data point</td>
    <td>data point</td>
    <td>data point</td>
    <td>data point</td>
    <td>
      <form>
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
    </td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It worked! thanks! (I had the table wrapped in a div and moved the `direction:rtl;` to the div instead of having it on the table.)